# Why can't a stable star have radius 1 < r < 9/8 its Schwarzschild radius?

Tags: astrophysics, black-holes, stars

From http://www.spacetimetravel.org/ssm/ssm.html :

> A mass of 1.78 [in geometric units] corresponds to a ratio of radius to Schwarzschild radius of 9/8. Theory predicts that a smaller ratio is not possible for a stable star.

What causes this cutoff?  Is this the [TOV limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit) or something else?

Comment: Far outside my competence, but I'll bet dollars to donuts it is related to the lack of stable orbits inside $3/2 r_0$. Things are just goofy when the curvature of space gets that high.

Comment: @dmckee: Perhaps, but 9/8 isn't that close to 3/2, so something else would have to be at work as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TOV limit is related to maximum mass that can be supported by the neutron degeneracy pressure. The $9/8$ ratio comes from General Relativistic arguments which state that any star that fills the Schwarzschild volume any more than $88\%$ will collapse under its gravitational field to end up as a Black Hole.

The $88\%$ limit ultimately comes from stellar stability to radial oscillations. The stability under these oscillations can be measured using the adiabatic exponent $\Gamma$ which is $\frac{\Delta P/P}{\Delta \rho/\rho}$. This would be in Newtonian dynamics. However, when dealing with General Relativity, we know that anything compactified to a radius less than its $R_S$ will collapse to a Black Hole. So even if $\Gamma\rightarrow \infty$, a star can still collapse. Interestingly, $\Gamma\rightarrow \infty$ corresponds to $R/R_S > 9/8$.

Comment: Can you explain this further?  I don't understand why it would collapse at this particular size.

Comment: Yes, of course. I've just expanded the original answer.

Comment: In case it's not clear from this answer, the 9/8 value is unrelated to the TOV limit.

Comment: This answer basically explains it. The relevant reference is [Chandrasekhar, ApJ **140**, 417 (1964)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1964ApJ...140..417C).